# What is the complexity of that code?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I was looking at code on this link:
http://codeforces.com/contest/459/submission/7495216
The code is that given a directed weighted graph and wanna find the longest path with strictly increasing edges.
Can anyone help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
const int MAX = 300005;
vector<pair<int, int> > w[MAX];
int dp[MAX], tmp[MAX];
int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        int u, v, len;
        cin >> u >> v >> len;
        w[len].push_back(make_pair(u, v));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < w[i].size(); j++)
        {
            int u = w[i][j].first, v = w[i][j].second;
            tmp[v] = 0;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < w[i].size(); j++)
        {
            int u = w[i][j].first, v = w[i][j].second;
            tmp[v] = max(tmp[v], dp[u] + 1);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < w[i].size(); j++)
        {
            int u = w[i][j].first, v = w[i][j].second;
            dp[v] = max(dp[v], tmp[v]);
        }
    }
    int ans = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        ans = max(ans, dp[i]);
    cout << ans << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To those voting to close: I don't think the question is too broad. Calculating the complexity of a function is pretty narrow. The close vote isn't a super-downvote.

Comment: @VincentSavard For this Q&A to become useful to anyone you would have to explain how to determine algorithmic complexity. This is too broad in my opinion. The author does not give a narrow enough issue about the general problem.

Comment: @typ1231 this may appear boring for you,well it's not for me

Answer (score 0):

For each node this code iterates over all outgoing edges. So the runtime complexity is O(n*m) where n is the number of nodes and m is the number edges.

Edit: After a closer look at the data and the code, I say the complexity is O(n+m). The first and the second loop iterate over all edges, so O(m), and the third loop iterates over all nodes, so O(n).

Comment: the author  of the code is saying it's O(n+m*log(m))

Comment: After a closer look at the code it is O(n+m) because the second loop only iterates over all edges. I'll correct my answer but I don't see a reason for m*log(m). There is no comparing sort involved. He's using bucket sort which has a complexity of O(m).